# Twitter Bootstrap event.relatedTarget to remove class?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

This should be fairly simple, but somehow not working.

I am trying to change the active class of list groups upon click with the help of bootstrap tab events.

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
            $(e.target).addClass('active'); // activated tab
            $(e.relatedTarget).removeClass('active'); // previous tab
            //alert ($(e.relatedTarget).attr('href'));
        });
```

I am able to add class to e.target but e.relatedTarget is not working. Any help?

```
<div class="list-group" id="MasterPageTabs">
     <a href="#lv" class="list-group-item active" data-toggle="tab">Language Variations</a>
     <a href="#hm" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="tab">Hotel Master</a>
     <a href="#gm" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="tab">Generics Master</a>
</div>
```

As you can refer, I am not using the default ul li structure for tabs, instead i am using the bootstrap 3 list groups with js for tabs.

Comment: what exactly is the purpose of this? the classes you are changing are changed already by bootstrap... http://bootply.com/72968

Comment: @Kevin, Modified my question. I have added the HTML in which you can see that i am not using the default ul li structure for tabs instead i am implementing the tabs in list groups. Bootstrap only change class in case of UL LI structure.

Comment: can you create an exmaple in bootply?

Comment: Bootply example: http://bootply.com/72974

Comment: relatedTarget is always undefined, i assume due to the different structure you are using. I'd suggest selecting all active, remove active, then make clicked active. http://bootply.com/72976

Comment: Well i can use jquery to solve this: $('#MasterPageTabs').find('.active').removeClass('active'); But i was thinking if bootstrap relatedTarget works with any tag or just ul li?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update** as the code from your comment show the (a) ul is used to select the elements.

You could try to extend / overwrite the show function of the tab plugin. Something like:

```
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script> 
            <script src="bootstrap3/bootstrap-3.0.0-wip/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script>
          $.fn.tab.Constructor.prototype.show = function () {
            var $this    = this.element

            selector = $this.attr('href')
            selector = selector && selector.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]*$)/, '') //strip for ie7

            var previous = $('.list-group').find('.active:last')[0]
            var e        = $.Event('show.bs.tab', {
              relatedTarget: previous
            })

            $this.trigger(e)

            if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) return

            var $target = $(selector)


            this.activate($target, $target.parent(), function () {
              $this.trigger({
                type: 'shown.bs.tab'
              , relatedTarget: previous
              })
            })
          } 


        $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
                    $(e.target).addClass('active'); // activated tab
                    console.log(e.relatedTarget);
                    $(e.relatedTarget).removeClass('active'); // previous tab            
                });
        </script>
```

<strike>Event.relatedTarget will always be `undefined` cause it is only set for mouse events. It has nothing to do with your structure or even Twitter Bootstrap.</strike>

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.relatedTarget

Comment: It has everything to do with bootstrap, this is a custom event being triggered by bootstrap, bootstrap is controlling the value of `event.relatedTarget`. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/3.0.0-wip/js/tab.js#L44

Comment: Had to slightly modify this code for my own use, but worked wonderfully! Thank you