# Determine the LI that was active before change

Tags: javascript

I have a series of bootstrap tabs and I need to fire an event when the tab is changed.

The base object of the tabbed interface is UL, and each tab is a LI.

I need to fire an event when the user selects a different tab (li), the event will need to determine the tab that was active when the user chose the new tab.

I was originally thinking about a global flag that is set when the user chooses a tab, then the event fires when the tab changes and it updates the global flag with the new selection...  but i am hoping there is a better way to determine the tab that was active prior to the change.

Comment: Have you tried event.relatedtarget?

Comment: ControlAltDel - please add this as an answer so i can select it.  This is exactly what i was looking.  thank you

Comment: This looks useful - I would not have thought of relatedtarget! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134292/twitter-bootstrap-event-relatedtarget-to-remove-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use event.relatedTarget to get the formerly selected LI